# Choosing values for marginal densities given non informative prior

Tags: bayesian

I am trying to understand how to choose values for marginal densities of the paramters given a non informative prior in a Bayesian linear regression model s.th.:

$$Y_n|X_{nk}, \beta_k, \sigma^2 \sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2I)$$

Given a non-informative prior $p(\beta, \sigma^2) \propto 1 / \sigma^2$ and the likelihood functions from above, the marginal distribution for the linear regression model are given by:

$$\sigma^2 \sim InvGamma(df/2, df*s2/2)$$ with $df = n - k$, and $$\beta \sim MvNormal(\beta, \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1})$$

Using an artificial data generated by:

$$ y = X\beta + \varepsilon\quad \varepsilon \sim N(0,1)$$ with
$$X \sim U(0,1), \quad\beta = (2,2,0.1)' $$

Now I came across a few tutorials [this](http://www.columbia.edu/~cjd11/charles_dimaggio/DIRE/styled-4/styled-11/code-8/#bayesian-regression-modeling-with-bugs-or-jags) or [this](http://www.bayes-pharma.org/Presentation_PDF/Winbugs_part2.pdf) where the authors use $\beta_i \sim N(0, 10^4)$ and $\sigma^2 \sim IG(1 / 10^4, 1 / 10^4)$.

My question is what is their reasoning for choosing those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect those values were chosen as they yield suitably vague priors.

A normal distribution centered at 0 with variance $10^4$ spreads the majority of its probability density (say, 95%) over the interval $(-200, 200)$, which is reasonably vague for many applications.  The inverse gamma case is similar.